# eslint role for empty line in start of function or arrow function

Tags: formatting, eslint, lint

There are a lot of options in the [`padding-line-between-statements`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/padding-line-between-statements) role, but I can't find a role that forces this code:

```js
const app = express()

app.use('/', (req, res) => {
    const x = req.body

    return x
})
```

To be with an empty line after `app.use`:

```js
const app = express()

app.use('/', (req, res) => {

    const x = req.body

    return x
})
```

Of course, for this example, I can use `{ blankLine: "always", prev: ["*"], next: "const"}`, but I'm looking for more generic solution.

The [`padded-blocks`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/padded-blocks) is almost what we need, except it add an empty line for both start and **end** of **any** block.

Comment: The [`padded-blocks`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/padded-blocks) rule may be useful here, but it requires empty lines at the top _and_ bottom instead of just the top. Let me know if this is what you're looking for and I'll make it into an answer.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to talk about that. This was the rule I started with, but the team members didn't like it